# sql query to display the result as follows

Tags: sql

table name is stud

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

Result expected :

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary, John, Sam
2               Alaina, Edward
```

using sql

could you help me guys

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT SubjectID, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentName)
FROM stud
GROUP BY SubjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000)  
   SELECT  @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + StudentName FROM stud
SELECT @Names
```

Comment: use Like above example

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which product this works with.